# Обновить переинициализированную переменную в функции

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables

Изначально переменная `disable` имеет значение `false`
В функции `drag()` она используется. 
Необходимо переинициализировать ее в функции `resize()` на событии `mousedown` или `mousemove`, точно не уверен, значением `true`. Проблема в том, что функция `drag()` после переинициализации уже не вызываетяся, это и не нужно, в принципе. А переменную в ней перезаписать нужно.

```
var disable = false;
function drag() {
    $('.sossage').draggable({
        axis: 'x',
        containment: "parent",
        snap: true,
        disabled: disable
    });
}

function resize() {
    $('.sossage')
        .mousedown(function (e) {
            offsetx = e.offsetX;
            var elWidth = parseInt($(this).css('width'));
            if (e.offsetX >= elWidth - 5 && e.offsetX <= elWidth) {
                my_target = e.target;
                resizeState = true;
                clientXforResize = e.clientX;
                initialWidth = parseInt($(this).css('width'));
            }
        })
        .mouseup(function (e) {
            resizeState = false;
            var elWidth = parseInt($(this).css('width'));
            if (e.offsetX >= elWidth - 5 && e.offsetX <= elWidth) {
                resizeState = false;
                my_target = null;
            }
        });

    $(document)
        .mousemove(function (e) {
            if (resizeState == true) {
                var widthOffset = clientXforResize - e.clientX;
                $(my_target).css({
                    'width': (initialWidth - widthOffset) + 'px'
                });
            }
        })
        .mouseup(function () {
            resizeState = false;
        });
}
```

Comment: Ответ вам уже написали, но позволю еще порекомендовать объединять связанные функции и данные, которые являются для них общими, в объекты. Или хотя бы оборачивать их в анонимные функции, чтобы не засорять глобальный контекст

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну функционально 'drag()' просто прикрепляет к '$('.sossage').' обЬект со свойствами 'axis', 'containment'...
После этого вы создаёте новый вариант '$('.sossage')' в 'function resize()'. И у этой версии массива этих свойств уже нет.
Вынеси декларацию '$('.sossage')' вне функций, назови её как нибудь и вызывай из откуда потребуется.

> 

```js
 var my_array = $('.ducks');

 function foo1() {
   my_array.someData = {
     myData: 'aaaa',
     sedcondData: 'bbb',
     funcEmb: function() {}
   };
 }

 function foo2() {
   my_array.someData.funcEmb();
   my_array.someData.myData = 'new data';
 }
```